# Upgrade from sharepoint 3.0 to Sharepoint Foundatation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration, wss-3.0

Have a client with a bit of a weird setup left behind by a predecessor, company is fairly small so not looking to pay out for full blown SharePoint or SQL.

They currently have a SharePoint services 3.0 running on a 2003 server this is on a different domain and forest to their actual domain.

For some reason it broke on the original one and they got it working but transferring the database to a new installation on a new domain/forest and creating a forest trust between however this had led to everyone putting in usernames and passwords each time the site is accessed.

This has a number of issues and I think best way forward is to get them back on their normal internal domain and working on SharePoint Foundation 2010.

From reading I cannot go from 3.0 to foundation 2013 so have chosen 2010 I have a method in place on how I am going to get the content over as that's the bit I am interested in not too fussed on permissions etc I can sort those out once install is running and they do need sorting in the process.

My only question really to the forum is what the effect is on their normal functioning working internal domain from a SharePoint view, something in the past broke, my plan is to install SharePoint on their secondary file server running 2008 r2 std and then import the content from the old db on 3.0, using a guide I have found, then sort out permissions etc and go from there.

Is there a chance the old sharepoint installation did things to the active directory schema/added accounts etc at all which is likely to cause the install to fail or anything active directory I should be concerned about.

I have recently brought their domain up to 2012 functional and forest level with 2 domain controllers.

Any help appreciated as I don't normally get too involved with SharePoint/SQL so my knowledge only goes so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact it started working on a new domain albeit with a login prompt was a coincidence but without any real detail about the original problem it would be hard to determine the issue.

SharePoint install and config does not make any changes to AD. The person installing SharePoint on the other hand... It sounds like a simple install so I'll hazard a guess that you are not using kerberos. But if you are/were you should check the forest for duplicate SPNs. Have a look at the -F switch on SetSPN (Windows 2008+).

If you haven't done so already you should also run DCDiag on all the DCs in the forest just to give you some reassurance.